# Expression to separate last iteration of a for loop

Tags: c#, expression

Is there another method to achieve the following result? (without using if)

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 16;
        Action[] action = new Action[2] { go0, go1 };
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i - 1);
            action[((i % (n)) % (i + 1)) / i]();
            //Console.Write(((i % (n)) % (i + 1)) / i);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void go0() { Console.Write("-"); }
    static void go1() { Console.Write("|"); }
```

EDIT :

ok I will try to be more specific. My real problem has to do with graphics.

I try to render a grid of white rectangles  and line separators between them. So when I enter the loop to draw each rectangle i also draw the right side of each rectangle with another color to make the separator distinct.

But when I come to the last rectangle I don't want to draw its right side. To overcome this I found that this approach may work, assuming the first method draws the separator and the second method draws nothing.

(I'm not a programmer, so it's difficult for me to express my self exactly, when talking about programming).

Comment: Is this [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) or a real problem?

Comment: Please, use `if`. I wouldn't want to support such code even as a punshment in hell.

Comment: If your repeating one too many, can't you just adjust your loop condition? Like `i = 1; i < n; i++`?

Answer (score 4):

> Basically I want to skip the last element of the loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
// ...
```